# Manage data returned by the server

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

if we want to modify some data who are returner by the server, what is the way to do it?

responseHandler?

i would like to transform some field who are boolean  to other value.

In the database, sex is manager with true or false (man = true).
So when true is returner, i would like to display man.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you're returning data from the server, but you can just use an if statement or a case statement if the situation is more complex.

```
    if(sex){
      sex = 'man'
    }
    else {
      sex = 'woman'
    }
```